# Convert Core Data parent entity to child entity

Tags: ios, core-data

Lets say I have Person entity -> sub-entity Employee -> sub-entity Manager. What I want is in some point change concrete employee to Manager. Is there easy way to do so, without manual deep copy?

Thanks

Comment: Don't use an entity hierarchy, use a flag attribute or a relationship to denote it...

Comment: I get a lot of other benefits from entity inheritance, so that's not an option. I prefer to solve this without changing current architecture.

Comment: What are those benefits? You must tear down the old one and build a new one...

Comment: Thats what I do, but I thought that because inherited entity is basically same table with parent entity in Core Data, there must be a way to convert entity without actually deleting and creating new.

Answer (score 0):

You cant change name of an entity in core data on the go. 
You should change the model and migrate it by light/heavy migration based on the changes you made..

IMO, I would go for a model which has only one entity called "Employee" since manager is also an employee.

Employee entity has attributes of your wish.

The employee entity would have relationship to itself.

Relationships-

manager- one-to-many with employeeSet

empleyeeSet-many to one with manager

If an employee is not a manager, he/she would have 0 employeeSet.count

[image]

Comment: My question has nothing to do with changing actual name of the entity description and not related to migration.